# How to use the value of a cell and insert that into a formula referencing a sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a  source sheet where I manipulate a number of other sheets with that "source data." I have created a drop down with all of the names of the sheets I need to reference.

I need to create a formula that changes based on this dropdown which includes sheet names.

[image]

If the formula was ='Sheet1'!E5 + 'Sheet1'!G5

But Sheet1 would be populated form the dropdown and E5 and G5 would just work normally I would assume. I am at a loss.

I have messed around with some INDIRECT commands but I can't seem to make that work. Not sure if that's the proper route.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Make a copy of your spreadsheet without personal data and update your question, to understand it is better that we can look at the case visually!

Comment: Uploaded one just now. Hope this helps. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```vb
=INDIRECT("'02/03/2020 - 08/03/2020'!C10", TRUE)
=INDIRECT("'"&<reference cell>&"'!C10", TRUE)
```

Or another more flexible way:

```vb
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(10, 3, 0, TRUE, "02/03/2020 - 08/03/2020"))
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(10, 3, 0, TRUE, <reference cell>))
```

Comment: I have a dropdown that lists each of my spreadsheet's names. I would like to be able to pick a sheet name from that list and have it fill in formulas accordingly. Is that possible or would I need a script?

Comment: @user13039528 your dropdown is form dropdown but not an in-cell dropdown? Why not use in-cell dropdown?

Comment: I have a dropdown list in a cell, J3, but when I put J3 in =INDIRECT("'"&<J3>&"'!C10", TRUE), it says that there is a parse error.

Comment: That worked! So sorry about the confusion, this is my first time posting here.

Comment: @user13039528 please accept answers that are useful to you, this is how Stack Overflow works so others can find this answer and learn from it in the future.